# Hypergeometric function with large parameters

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I need an efficient and accurate method to evaluate hypergeometric ratios of the form:

$$\frac{_{2}F_{1}(a+1,b;c;x)}{_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;x)}$$

for large positive values of `a`, `b`, `c`. However, if you plot:

```
Plot[Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[601, Rationalize[100.1], 100, x]/
     Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[600, Rationalize[100.1], 100, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

you will see that these ratios can be inaccurate in *Mathematica*.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `N` on exact input avoids the round-off error from calculating the two hypergeometric functions separately.  (I stopped before `x = 1`, since that produces a divide-by-zero error.)

```
ListLinePlot@
 N@Table[Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[601, Rationalize[100.1], 100, x] / 
         Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[600, Rationalize[100.1], 100, x],
   {x, 0, 1 - 1/100, 1/100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, one could use a relatively high `WorkingPrecision`:

```
Plot[Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[601, Rationalize[100.1], 100, x] /
     Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[600, Rationalize[100.1], 100, x],
 {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

(Pretty much the same graph as above.)

Comment: Michael, I know this is old, and sorry for the noob question, but can you please elaborate on this 'divide by zero' error you talk about, with variable = 1 (exactly)?

Comment: @299792458 I'm referring to the fact that `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[600, Rationalize[100.1], 100, 1]` throws a divide by zero error (`Power::infy`).

Answer (score 2):

Using one of the [three-term recurrences satisfied by ${}_2 F_1$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/01/0001/), and exploiting the fact that $a$ and $c$ are integers, here is an implementation of the continued fraction expansion of the hypergeometric function ratio in the OP:

```
ratio2f1[a_Integer?Positive, b_, c_Integer?Positive, z_] :=
     ((a (z - 2) - b z + c)/a +
      ContinuedFractionK[(a - k - c)/(a - k) (z - 1),
                         ((a - k - 1) (z - 2) - b z + c)/(a - k - 1),
                         {k, 0, a - 2}])/(z - 1)
```

This implementation is now quite stable for plotting purposes:

```
Plot[{Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[601, 1001/10, 100, x]/
      Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[600, 1001/10, 100, x],
      ratio2f1[600, 1001/10, 100, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], AbsoluteThickness[2]}]
```

[image: plot of hypergeometric function ratio, explicit vs. CF]

---

Let me also present an alternative implementation that avoids using `ContinuedFractionK[]`, which may be useful for e.g. making a compiled function. I used the [Lentz-](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.15.000668)[Thompson-Barnett](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991%2886%2990046-X) algorithm to evaluate the continued fraction:

```
ratio2f1[a_Integer?Positive, b_, c_Integer?Positive, z_] := Module[{ak, bk, ck, dk, f},
     f = ck = (a (z - 2) - b z + c)/a; dk = 0;
     Do[ak = (a - k - c)/(a - k) (z - 1); 
        bk = ((a - k - 1) (z - 2) - b z + c)/(a - k - 1);
        dk = 1/(bk + ak dk); ck = bk + ak/ck; f *= ck dk,
        {k, 0, a - 2}];
     f/(z - 1)]
```